# How can I save my tangerine tree after repotting and leaves curling?

Tags: leaves, bonsai, citrus, repotting

I have a 10 year old tangerine tree.

It put on a ton of new leafy growth this summer when I had it outside, but I pruned a lot of the branches to make it look more uniform.

It was in a pretty big pot and I wanted it to look more like a proper bonsai, so I repotted it in a shallower pot. While repotting, I trimmed some roots to remove a deep tap root, and fanned out the roots in the new pot to promote a radial root system.

I used Miracle Gro Cactus, Palm, and Citrus soil.

I also added some moss from my backyard to contribute to the bonsai look.

I saturated the soil with water mixed with Miracle Gro All Purpose Plant Food per the directions on the box.

I then let the soil almost dry out before watering again, because I didn't want to over water the tree.

The tree then began to curl its leaves and one of the newer growth branches died. What can I do to save this tree?[image: Tangerine Tree]

Comment: Just to understand the question better: You repotted the plant and then let it almost dry out?